# Проблемы с OpenVPN (или Windows?)

Tags: openvpn

Есть сервер OpenVPN на Windows 7 и клиент на XP. все соединяется, адреса, созданные OpenVPN пингуются. но при попытке открыть сервер в проводнике (пишу в адресной строке \10.9.0.1) сообщение

"Нет доступа к \10.9.0.1. Возможно, у вас нет прав на использование этого сетевого ресурса. Обратитесь к администратору этого сервера для получения соответствующих прав доступа. Вход в систему не произведен: выбранный режим входа для данного пользователя на этом компьютере не предусмотрен."

Не спрашивает даже имя и пароль

Comment: а так уже пробовали писать \\10.9.0.1? две косые.

Comment: конечно, просто описка в тексте, не заметил\